# php script using json encode loading only first record

Tags: php, mysql, json, encode, selectall

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php' ;

$sql = "SELECT Title,Date,Time,Location,image_url FROM events ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {


    $data = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $data['events'] = $row ;

    }

} 


echo json_encode($data); 
header('Content-Type: application/json');

?>
```

Comment: You are overwriing `$data['events']` each time.  Try `$data['events'][] = $row;
`

Comment: $sql = "SELECT Title,Date,Time,Location,image_url FROM events limit 0,1";

Comment: @AbraCardaver now ive got blank page

Comment: @SandraKhazaal dont send a header after outputing. Learn to read your server logs, use an IDE.\

Comment: @Purushottamzende now it is getting liKE IN DESC order and staying 1 record

Comment: Wheres the question? This is a lost cause.

Comment: @SandraKhazaal $sql = "SELECT Title,Date,Time,Location,image_url FROM events order by time asc limit 0,1"; or which ever column you want

Comment: @IncredibleHat the ques is why its getting for me only the first record?

Comment: @Purushottamzende i did so , its never changed

Answer (score 5):

Insert entries in the list, with few minor suggestions

```
require_once 'connect.php' ;

$sql = "SELECT Title,Date,Time,Location,image_url FROM events ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Move $data declaration up for zero result.
$data = array('events' => []);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       // Insert $rows in events array
       $data['events'][] = $row ;

    }
} 

// Send headers first before sending any data
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: It should not, check you php error reporting for any other error, enable all errors.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code presented above in this answer. A blank page is most likely user error on Sandra's part due to sloppy copy/pasting.

Comment: Then what i can do?

Comment: @anwerj Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/abbassne/public_html/DoctorMobileApp/connect.php:16) in /home/abbassne/public_html/DoctorMobileApp/Events.php on line 21

Comment: @anwerj then i tried removing json header ..then also get me a blank page

Comment: Remove any `echo` or `print_r` from your connect.php(line 16) file, go through this to understand more.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: @anwerj it was Whitespace after ?> in connect.php line 16..I've removed the space and keep ?> ..it gets me raw data empty again and SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 5 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: @anwerj also i get through the link .. and says for my case Whitespace after ?>

If the error source is mentioned as behind the closing ?> then this is where some whitespace or raw text got written out. The PHP end marker does not terminate script executation at this point. Any text/space characters after it will be written out as page content still.

It's commonly advised, in particular to newcomers, that trailing ?> PHP close tags should be omitted. This eschews a small portion of these cases. (Quite commonly include()d scripts are the culprit.)

Comment: @anwerj so i tried to ommit ?> from connect.php but it stays the same with raw data empty and syntax error for json part